# h2o.weights() return None

Tags: python, h2o

I built an autoencoder (AE) in **h2o ver. 3.24.0.3 python** with `"export_weights_biases"=TRUE`. After training, I tried to get my AE model weights by AE.weights(0). At first, it returns the weights matrix. But then I saved my AE model, and load it again after I shutdown my h2o cluster. I tried to get the weights again but it returns "None". Can someone help?

```
params={....
        'export_weights_and_biases':True,}

ae_model=H2OAutoEncoderEstimator(**params)
ae_model.train(x=X,training_frame=data)

w=ae_model.weights(0)
```

Expected: H2OFrame of weights with input*layer dimension
Actual: None